# ExtJS TriggerField set value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'd created SelectOne component extending TriggerField, setted onTriggerClick to open new Window with Grid there on OK or dblclick mast set triggerfield value like this:

```
val = {
  id: "1234",
  text: "Selected value"
}
```

My problem is, how to return **id** on getValue() or form submit and **text** to input field of triggerfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to override the  `rawToValue` and `getSubmitValue` methods of your CustomTrigger and add a custom value to hold the selected information from your grid.

You would define your trigger like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomTrigger', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
    alias: 'widget.customtrigger',
    config : {
        option : null
    },
    // override rawToValue method
    rawToValue: function() {        
       return  this.getOption();
    }, 
    // override getSubmitValue method
    getSubmitValue : function () {
        return this.getOption()
    }
    // override onTriggerClick
    onTriggerClick: function() {
       ....
    }
}
```

On your grid, the ok button and itemdblclick handlers should use the `triggerfield.setOption()` method to hold the selected value and use `triggerfield.setValue('Selected Value')` so your trigger field reads  "Selected Value".

Now, when you call `triggerfield.getValue()` you will get the same value as `triggerfield.getOption()` but it will display "Selected value"

I created this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c1c so you could understand this a little better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'd made some changes in your fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c1e

Comment: No problem Limon, whatever works best for you. However, you should not use the TriggerField with ExtJS 5 as this Class has been deprecated since 5.0. For versions from 5.0 up you should use the triggers configuration in the Textfield class.

Comment: Limon, I've update my fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c1c) to do what you wanted with less code. Hope it helps